# Master Projects in SharePoint without Project Server

Tags: task-list, synchronisation, project-server, ms-project

We have MS Project plans and synchronise them to SharePoint tasklists.

When working offline with MS Project we are able to do a masterplan and manage resource access and dependencies between different projects.

Is there a way to synchronise these dependencies between projects to SharePoint **without** the useage of Project Server?

I fear there isn't, because MS wouldn't sell Project Server licenses, but maybe we're lucky and there are some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look a the [Project Team Planner?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/project/archive/2009/10/08/project-2010-introducing-the-team-planner.aspx) It looks like a feature of Project 2010 Professional that can [sync SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/project/archive/2009/10/19/project-2010-introducing-sync-to-sharepoint.aspx) which would connect the Team Planner with SharePoint.  I don't have the system setup to help you with how it works or comment on its effectiveness but here are a few resources:

Hope this helps you.

Microsoft Project 2010 Team Planner View & Microsoft Project Professional 2010 Demo
http://www.microsoft.com/global/project/en-us/RichMedia/demos/keystone/player.html?course=teamplanner

Project 2010: Introducing the Team Planner
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/project/archive/2009/10/08/project-2010-introducing-the-team-planner.aspx

Project 2010: Introducing Sync to SharePoint
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/project/archive/2009/10/19/project-2010-introducing-sync-to-sharepoint.aspx

View your team's work with Team Planner
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-help/view-your-team-s-work-with-team-planner-HA010373239.aspx